# Cannot update ui-select2 content from $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

The simplified version of my code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("App", ['ui.select2']);
app.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.select2Options1 = {
        data: [{id: 0, text: "Foo"}, {id: 1, text: "Bar"}]
    };

    $scope.select2Options2 = {
        data: []
    };

    $scope.$watch('chosen1', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== undefined && newVal !== null) {
            console.log("Valid value selected: " + newVal);
            $scope.select2Options2.data.push({id: 0, text: "FooBar"});
        }
    });
});
```

The markup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">
    <input ng-controller="MainController" ng-model="chosen1" ui-select2="select2Options1" style="width:100px">
    <input ng-controller="MainController" ng-model="chosen2" ui-select2="select2Options2" style="width:100px">

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do, is to update the contents of a `ui-select2` (`$scope.select2Options2.data`), when something gets chosen from another `ui-select2` (`$scope.select2Options1.data`).

The problem is that the contents of the second `ui-select2` is not updated no matter what I do in the handler of the `$scope.$watch`. If I move this `$scope.select2Options2.data.push({id: 0, text: "FooBar"});` outside the watch handler, it works and the second `ui-select2` gets populated. This means, that there must be something fundamentally wrong.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for the problem seemed to be the fact that I had defined MainController in the HTML twice. Wrapping everything inside a single div with ng-controller="MainController" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not using the module as recommended. Please read the documentation at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2.

The way to enable options on a `<select>` in Angular is to use the ng-options directive. However, ui-select2 doesn't fully support this directive, and recommends using `<option>` tags instead. In your case that should be something like:

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="select2" data-placeholder="Pick a number">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in select2Options2" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Please note that, unlike using ng-options, the selected object stored via ng-model, in this case will be a string representation, not the actual object. This is a limitation when using ui-select2. So please be aware that what's stored in chosen2 will be the value of `{{item.id}}` (a string), not the `{id: 0, text: "Foo"}` object.

Last, why did it partly work in your case?
Reason is, you were using select2 internal functions to generate the options. This works like normal upon initialization, but there is no watch set on this select2options.data field (Select2 doesn't know anything about Angular). So whatever data was there upon initialization would show up, but any updates would not.

Comment: Well, that didn't change anything. I still cannot change the data. I now also noticed, that I cannot change anything at all from $scope.$watch, not even a simple text gets updated. The handler is executed as I can see my console logs from there.

Comment: I tried to set $scope.Hello = "Hello!" in the $scope.$watch handler, but nothing happens (markup <div ng-controller="MainController"><h4>{{Hello}}</h4></div>). Either I'm really stupid or these things are poorly documented, but in any case I'm confused.